# Background color on just bullet part of <li> tag

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a bulleted list where the background color of just the left-margin (bullet) of the tag has a background color. I've tried in vain to find a solution online, just wondering if any CSS experts can suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that right what you want?
This code makes red background color on left of li tag

```
<style>
    ul{background-color: red;}
    li{margin-left: 10px; background-color:white;}
</style>


<ul>
    <li> aaaaa </li>
    <li> bbbb <li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use transparent backgrounds (which you can't with the other two proposed answers), an alternative approach is to use pseudo elements.

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
li {
  position: relative;
}
li:before {
  background: blue;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{background:coral}
li{background:green}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bd0jgrt/)